# Oracle session timezone: Can Oracle DB session convert java.sql.Date to correct timezone?

Tags: java, oracle, timezone, prepared-statement, oracle12c

We have an audit table( Columns/Types: ID/Number,.. Audited_Date/Date) which logs audit entries using prepared statements. Until now, for different contexts we set the database session timezone for the connection, after which we were using the CURRENT_DATE attribute for the audited_date column. THIS MEANT THAT THE DATE INSERTED INTO THE COLUMN IS IN THE TIMEZONE OF THE CONNECTION WHICH IS IMPORTANT.

Now, we have a new requirement to add different dates based on the supplied timestamps for the audit logs. Similar to the previous approach where the auditing engine didn't have to worry about the timezone, is there a way to set the date for the column, WITHOUT having to do something like this:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone);
calendar.setTimeZone(timeZone);
preparedStatement.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(userTimestampMillis), calendar);
```

I would really like NOT to do this because the timezone attribute is decided based on multiple attributes like system environments, and other parameters. The application uses ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE="CONTEXT_TIMEZONE" in a global scope of the application where connections are fetched from.
**Is there any way to let the DB session handle the timezone conversion?**

These two approaches fail to convert the the timestamp to the DB session timezone. If i'm not wrong, they are using the JVM timezone.

FAIL1.

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(userTimestampMillis);
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, timestamp);
```

FAIL2.

```
preparedStatement.setObject(4, new java.sql.Date(userTimestampMillis));
```

Any documentation is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`DATE`s are not time zone aware, so you probably want to work with something in the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type. You say you can correctly set the database session time zone, so you're mostly there. Say you're in Los Angeles and my database session is in Chicago:

```
alter session set time_zone = 'America/Chicago';

Session altered.

select current_timestamp from dual;

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                            
---------------------------------------------
2018-07-27 20:30:28.672000000 AMERICA/CHICAGO

select cast( current_timestamp at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles' as date ) as d from dual;

D                  
-------------------
2018-07-27 18:30:28
```

So you basically need to use `AT TIME ZONE` to convert the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` into the correct time zone, then use `CAST ( ... AS DATE )` to turn that into a `DATE`, which basically just trucates off the time zone information and doesn't do any conversion.

Comment: Don't think this helps me. Is there a way to say `insert into table ... values (.., <MyTimestamp> at $CURRENT_DB_TIMEZONE)?

Comment: That's what `AT TIME ZONE` does.